# FileError: 'http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/catalog/lib/style/bootstrap-3.0.1/variables.less' wasn't found (404)

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, profile, iso-19115

After installing the *geonetwork* version 3.2.1 and the plugin of the *iso19115-3* everything work fine. But when plugin the *lampv2* profile, this error message shows:

```
## FileError: 'http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/catalog/lib/style/bootstrap-3.0.1/variables.less' wasn't found (404)
in bootstrap.less on line 2, column 1:

1// Core variables and mixins
2@import "variables.less";

3@import "mixins.less"; ##


Raised exception while starting the application. Fix the error and restart.
    Message


    Failed whilst validating schema-ident file C:\geonetwork\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\config\schema_plugins\iso19115-3.2018\schema-ident.xml. Exception message if any is XSD Validation error(s):
    <xsderrors>
      <error>
        <typeOfError>ERROR</typeOfError>
        <errorNumber>1</errorNumber>
        <message>cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'appMinorVersionSupported'. One of '{"http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":title, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":description, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":standardUrl, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":depends, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":schemaLocation}' is expected. (Element: appMinorVersionSupported with parent element: schema)</message>
        <xpath>appMinorVersionSupported</xpath>
      </error>
    </xsderrors>
    Handler 
    org.fao.geonet.Geonetwork
    Exception   
    OperationAbortedEx : Failed whilst validating schema-ident file C:\geonetwork\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\config\schema_plugins\iso19115-3.2018\schema-ident.xml. Exception message if any is XSD Validation error(s):
    <xsderrors>
      <error>
        <typeOfError>ERROR</typeOfError>
        <errorNumber>1</errorNumber>
        <message>cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'appMinorVersionSupported'. One of '{"http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":title, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":description, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":standardUrl, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":depends, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":schemaLocation}' is expected. (Element: appMinorVersionSupported with parent element: schema)</message>
        <xpath>appMinorVersionSupported</xpath>
      </error>
    </xsderrors>
    Stack   
    OperationAbortedEx : Failed whilst validating schema-ident file C:\geonetwork\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\data\config\schema_plugins\iso19115-3.2018\schema-ident.xml. Exception message if any is XSD Validation error(s):
    <xsderrors>
      <error>
        <typeOfError>ERROR</typeOfError>
        <errorNumber>1</errorNumber>
        <message>cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'appMinorVersionSupported'. One of '{"http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":title, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":description, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":standardUrl, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":depends, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":schemaLocation}' is expected. (Element: appMinorVersionSupported with parent element: schema)</message>
        <xpath>appMinorVersionSupported</xpath>
      </error>
    </xsderrors>
        at org.fao.geonet.kernel.SchemaManager.processSchema(SchemaManager.java:1287)
        at org.fao.geonet.kernel.SchemaManager.configure(SchemaManager.java:226)
        at org.fao.geonet.Geonetwork.start(Geonetwork.java:241)
        at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.initAppHandler(JeevesEngine.java:448)
        at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.init(JeevesEngine.java:191)
        at jeeves.server.sources.http.JeevesServlet.init(JeevesServlet.java:84)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:640)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:437)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1510)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1435)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
    Caused by: XSDValidationErrorEx : XSD Validation error(s):
    <xsderrors>
      <error>
        <typeOfError>ERROR</typeOfError>
        <errorNumber>1</errorNumber>
        <message>cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'appMinorVersionSupported'. One of '{"http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":title, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":description, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":standardUrl, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":depends, "http://geonetwork-opensource.org/schemas/schema-ident":schemaLocation}' is expected. (Element: appMinorVersionSupported with parent element: schema)</message>
        <xpath>appMinorVersionSupported</xpath>
      </error>
    </xsderrors>
        at org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml.validate(Xml.java:878)
        at org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml.validate(Xml.java:862)
        at org.fao.geonet.kernel.SchemaManager.processSchema(SchemaManager.java:1273)
        ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you have pasted seems related to the file https://github.com/metadata101/iso19115-3.2018/blob/3.7.x/src/main/plugin/iso19115-3.2018/schema-ident.xml#L8. This schema is not supported by GN v3.2.x. Minimum version required is 3.5. You have available other ISO 19115-3 schema for GN v3.2.x at https://github.com/metadata101/iso19115-3/tree/3.2.x

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!